# Subquerys in cakephp 3.x, new ORM?

Tags: cakephp, orm, subquery, cakephp-3.x

I'm new in Cakephp 3.x and I'm having some trouble to create a subquery in the new ORM format. I have this report in my application, that needs to return the follow result:
1. There are three entities - Users, Calls, CallStatus.
2. Users hasMany Calls, Calls hasMany CallStatus.
3. I need to count how many CallStatus each user has in Calls.
Now follow the query that I need to put on new ORM format:

```
SELECT U.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls as C WHERE C.call_status_id =1 and C.user_id=U.id) AS 'Unavailable',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls as C WHERE C.call_status_id =2 and C.user_id=U.id) AS 'Busy',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls as C WHERE C.call_status_id =3 and C.user_id=U.id) AS 'Contacted',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls as C WHERE C.call_status_id =4 and C.user_id=U.id) AS 'Error'
FROM `users` AS U 
WHERE U.profile=3 and U.is_active=1
```

Could someone give me a help, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to see the number of calls for every callstatus you have for a specific user.

Try the following. Note that I used the CakePHP convention for naming the callstatuses (which is plural).

```
// get the tableregistry  
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$callstatuses = Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Callstatuses');

// for user with id 2, get the number of calls for each callstatus
$callstatuses->find()
    ->contain(['Calls'])
    ->where(['Calls.user_id' => 2, 'User.is_active' => 1])
    ->countBy('name')
    ->toArray();

// output could be:
//[ 'Unavailable' => 2, 'Busy' => 1 ]
```

You can find information about creating queries in the CakePHP book: see ['Query Builder'.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)

If you want to know more about working with/on queries, note that queries are Collections. Anything you can do on a Collection object, you can also do in a Query object. See the [Collection section in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use subqueries, as many as you want!
Here is an example for your case:

```
$q = $this->Calls->find();


$q1->select([$q->func()->count('*')])
      ->where(['Calls.user_id = Users.id', 'call_status_id' => 1]);

$q2->select([$q->func()->count('*')])
      ->where(['Calls.user_id = Users.id', 'call_status_id' => 2]);

$q3->select([$q->func()->count('*')])
      ->where(['Calls.user_id = Users.id', 'call_status_id' => 3]);

$q4->select([$q->func()->count('*')])
      ->where(['Calls.user_id = Users.id', 'call_status_id' => 4]);

$qUsers = $this->Users->find()
         ->select([
              'id',  
              'first_name',  
              'Unavailable' => $q1,
              'Busy' => $q2,
              'Contacted' => $q3,
              'Error' => $q4
         ])
         ->where(['profile' => 3, 'active' => 1])
         ->all();
```

Note: That nicer if you use a loop to create suqueries in this case.